# Sencha Cmd 4: minify the javascript code of ExtJS and Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

I have developed two applications using ExtJS and Sencha Touch. I would like to minify the JavaScript code and create a single js file for all classes used in the applications (separately, I am trying to minify the code and not to build. My task doesn't depend on ExtJS or Sencha Touch).

I used sencha cmd verions 4 to do. It am facing some issues with both ExtJS and Sencha Touch application.

In ExtJS, It is not taking all the classes for minifying and creating a single js file. It is taking the classes which are mentioned in required method. If I want to minify the all the javascript classes, I will have to include all the classes in require method in app.js. This is not fair.

I used the following command. It is not giving any error

```
sencha -sdk <path-to-sdk> compile --classpath=<classpath> page -in index.html -out build/index.html -yui
```

In Sencha Touch, It is targetting for mobile environment (eg: Andriod, iPhone, windows, etc.). I am trying to compile and minify and not to package application.

Please let me know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is working as intended. Sencha build process looks for dependencies (via require) and loads them accordingly, getting you the smallest build necessary. Good practice is to always set your requires.

To get around this, if you really want to just include all classes, you can add standalone requires to the top of the app. Since Ext.Loader can accept wildcards, you can just do **Ext.require('App.model.*')** and it will load all the individual model files, for example.